# Quickblox 'automatic push notifications for offline user' not working

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, quickblox

I have following scenario.
User A sends message to User B in foreground -- this is working
Send push notification to User B, when app is in background, from 'Messages' console -- this is working

I want to send notification alert to User B when app is in background. I read that this is done automatically by quickblox, but is not happening for me.

I have followed instructions on [this link](http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Alerts)

I am using 'Starter' account in development mode. Do we need account with ' server side history' for this functionality?

**Edit 1**:
Clarification: I want to send '**automatic push notifications for offline user**' and not notification from app. I am also sending 'save_to_history' flag as mentioned on the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

We have to **logout from the the chat when the app enters background**. 
I think, this might be required to let server know that we are actually offline and it should send us push notification instead. (just a guess!!)

I think logout thing was mentioned in documentation as well but I didn't know that it was so important.

Comment: Yes, here it is http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Chat_in_background_mode

Answer (score 1):

for Sending push notification use below code

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   [self sendMessageNotification:@"Hello Push notification" :1234 ];
}

-(void)sendMessageNotification:(NSInteger)recipientID message:(NSString*)message
{
    isSentPushNotification = YES;
    //[self sendPushNotificationToUser:message ids:@"1" audioFileName:@"default"];

    NSMutableDictionary *payload = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableDictionary *aps = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [aps setObject:@"default" forKey:QBMPushMessageSoundKey];
    [aps setObject:message forKey:QBMPushMessageAlertKey];
    [aps setObject:@"1" forKey:QBMPushMessageAlertLocArgsKey];
    [payload setObject:aps forKey:QBMPushMessageApsKey];
    QBMPushMessage *pushMessage = [[QBMPushMessage alloc] initWithPayload:payload];
    // Send push to users with ids 292,300,1395
    [QBRequest sendPush:pushMessage toUsers:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(long)recipientID]successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBMEvent *event) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully dilivered push notification");
    } errorBlock:^(QBError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Fail to diliver push notification %@",error);

    }];
}
```

But you should first Subscribe User to receive Push Notifications

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    // Register subscription with device token
    [QBRequest registerSubscriptionForDeviceToken:deviceToken successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray *subscriptions) {
        // Registration succeded
    } errorBlock:^(QBError *error) {
        // Handle error
    }];
}
```

for more detail please have a look of [this](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios)

Comment: Please also create session before using any API of Quick blox

Comment: Sorry for late reply and confusion. I actually want to send 'automatic push notifications for offline user' not notification from app. I have updated the question also.

Comment: as I know for sending push notification we need only user id. it is not dependent on user status either online or offline. please check your log after sending push notification

Comment: Hey, found the solution to my problem. Thanks for help though.